# Define ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element in a config file / ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have put all my Zend Form Stuff in a .ini file. Things like:

```
elements.foo.type                                            = "text"
elements.foo.options.required                                = true
elements.foo.options.label                                   = "bar"
elements.foo.options.size                                    = "32"
elements.foo.options.maxLength                               = "64"
```

How can I add some `ZendX_JQuery_Elements` in my configuration file?

I have loaded jQuery in my application.ini and used it in my layout with `$this->jQuery();`

```
elements.baz.type = "datepicker"
```

works.

But I can't add some decorators on the regular way in my specific ini file.

The Errormessage for the Decorators:

> Cannot render jQuery form element without at least one decorator implementing the 'ZendX_JQuery_Form_Decorator_UiWidgetElementMarker' interface. Default decorator for this marker interface is the 'ZendX_JQuery_Form_Decorator_UiWidgetElement'. Hint: The ViewHelper decorator does not render jQuery elements correctly.

How can I decorate these things?